# creating new column while using group_by, quantile and other functions takes long time and doesn't gives desired outcome

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe of 100 columns and 2 million rows. Among the columns three column are `year, compound_id, lt_rto`. Hare

```
length(unique(year))
30

length(unique(compound_id))
642
```

What I want to do is create a new column named avg_rto that is  for each `year` and each `compound_id`  the mean for lowest 12% of `lt_rto` values. For example - suppose for `year` 2001, and `coumpund_id` xyz, it will find the all the values of `lt_rto` that are at lower 12% and calculate the mean. This mean will be at the rows where `year == 2001 & comound_id == "xyz"` .

The code I came up is -

```
dt <- dt %>% group_by(year, compound_id) %>%  
        mutate( avg_rto =  mean( dt[['lt_rto']] < quantile(fun.zero.omit(dt[['lt_rto']]),  
                                                                 probs = .88, na.rm = TRUE ) ))
```

**Note:** I also intend to omit the zero values while calculating the lower 12 % value.

The above code gives me same value for all the observations. And this also takes a lot time.

My problem is I can not figure out what's wrong on the code and how can I reduce the run time.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function which ignores 0 values and calculates mean of lowest 12%.

```
mean_of_lower_12_perc <- function(x) {
  val <- x[x != 0]
  mean(sort(val)[1:(0.12 * length(val))], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

Now apply this function by group.

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% 
  group_by(year, compound_id) %>%  
  mutate( avg_rto = mean_of_lower_12_perc(lt_rto))
```

If your data is huge you can try `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[, avg_rto := mean_of_lower_12_perc(lt_rto)]
```